# How to update existing objects dynamically, without creating new ones?

Tags: java, spring

I have an `User` class:

```
public class User {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String ssn;
   private int age;
   private double height;
   private double weight;
}
```

And an `UpdateUserDTO` class:

```
public class UpdateUserDTO {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private double height;
   private double weight;
}
```

The `UpdateUserDTO` is used in the PUT request body to update the user's data. At least one of the fields is required to be **not null** in the `UpdateUserDTO` instance, but the client **can update as many as he wants**, so I am expecting this instance to have a different number of **not null** values each time a new request is received.

I retrieve the User class (original data) from the database, and I want to map the **not null** fields from the `UpdateUserDTO` to the `User` class.

**I don't want to do it using many `if-else` statements.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Does anyone how I can do this* manually with `if-else` Statements

Comment: You either do it by hand or you can use [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org) or a similar library. All of them should have facilities for updating existing objects instead of creating new ones.

Comment: Apache Commons has BeanUtils copy properties method that i think works by reflection

Comment: @Jens I want to update the fields dynamically

Comment: *dynamically* means?

Comment: @Jens dynamically means not manually

Comment: @Caroline I don't understand what you are trying to avoid... what's the drawback in the if else statements?

Comment: You can use [Jackson annotation
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html) to ignore the fields with value null

Comment: @Essay97 I would like to avoid adding one more if-else statement in the source code every time I add a new property to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your first choice ModelMapper is still something you want to use, it should perfectly work for your case. The User class has to provide the required `setName(String name)` method.

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;

public class ModelMapperExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    User user = new User(); // simplified, retrieved from elsewhere
    UpdateUserDTO updated = new UpdateUserDTO(); // simplified, retrieved from elsewhere
    updated.setName("Paula");
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.map(updated, user);
    System.out.println(user.getName()); // prints Paula
  }
}
```

See Javadoc for more information on this: http://modelmapper.org/javadoc/org/modelmapper/ModelMapper.html#map-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-

Comment: And if there are more attributes tat are filled in `User` not in `UpdateUserDTO`?

Comment: @Jens I am not sure if I do understand your question. Can you explain your concerns?

Comment: user.setAge(23) and userDTO.setAge(null), if you map this? Is then user.getAge() null or 23?

Comment: @Jens ModelMapper provides TypeMaps with explicit mapping. You can also skip properties and use converters to handle such an case. For more details I would recommend http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/